# Find tension through rope binding hammock to two trees

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations, physics

Could you give me your feedback ?

> Someone with a mass of $60$ kg is sleeping in a hammock tied to a tree on each end with a rope. The two ropes form an angle of $45^\circ$ with the horizontal. How strong is the force through one of the ropes? If the angle was $30^\circ$, would the force be bigger?

We have

$\sin 45° = \cos 45° = \sqrt{2}/2$

We split our forces in horizontal and vertical components. The horizontal tensions must cancel each others, and the two vertical tensions must cancel the gravity force that pulls the person down.

$$T_1 \cos45° - T_2 \cos45° = 0$$
$$T_1 \sin45° + T_2 \sin45° = F_G = 60 \cdot 9.81$$

We get $T_1 = T_2 = F_G/(2 \cdot \sin45°)$

If we had an angle of $30^\circ$ we would have $\sin30^\circ < \sin45^\circ$ which implies $F_G/\sin30^\circ > F_G/\sin45^\circ$ so the tension through the rope would be bigger (and smaller for $60^\circ$)

---

Could you give me your feeback ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Your analysis is correct.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thank you so much ! Our math teachers don’t give solutions to the problems so it can be hard to know if the students found the solution. Feel free to post your comment as an answer, I will accept and upvote it